# How do I add a commandbar to the MasterDetailsView?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to add a commandbar to the MasterDetailsView, but I cannot figure out how to add the control using straight XAML.

Here's my code:

```
      <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" Name="CommandBar" >
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle" />
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat" />
        <AppBarSeparator/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Stop" Label="Stop" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" />

        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Like" Label="Like" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" Label="Dislike" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>

    <controls:MasterDetailsView MasterCommandBar="{x:Bind CommandBar}"
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="MasterDetailsViewControl"

        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleItems, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
        DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"
        NoSelectionContentTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectionContentTemplate}"
        BorderBrush="Transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CommandBar like such:

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView MasterCommandBar="{x:Bind CommandBar}"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="MasterDetailsViewControl"

    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"
    NoSelectionContentTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectionContentTemplate}"
    BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle" />
        </CommandBar>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
</controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

You should also be able to put the CommandBar into your page resources and apply using the resource

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CommandBar x:Key="MasterCommandBar" >
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle" />
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat" />
        <AppBarSeparator/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Stop" Label="Stop" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" />

        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Like" Label="Like" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" Label="Dislike" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.Resources>

<controls:MasterDetailsView MasterCommandBar="{StaticResource MasterCommandBar}"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="MasterDetailsViewControl"

    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"
    NoSelectionContentTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectionContentTemplate}"
    BorderBrush="Transparent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the big help!  One question, my CommandBar is always displayed at the bottom whether you insert it at MasterCommandBar or DetailsCommandBar.  Can this be placed at the top or will I have to do serious surgery like using a controltemplate?

Comment: By default the CommandBar is placed at the bottom. You can place it at the top by restyling the MasterDetailsView